# R: compilation failed for package 'slam'

Tags: r, windows-8.1, text-mining, tm, slam

I am using R 2.15.2 and I want to install the tm package to do some text analysis.
I have downloaded the compatible **tm** package from the [CRAN archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tm/). I downloaded **tm_0.5-9**

I tried to install it using

```
install.packages("/Downloads/tm_0.5-9.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source", dependencies = TRUE)
```

and got the following error

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependency 'slam' is not available for package 'tm'
* removing '/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/tm'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   "/Downloads/tm_0.5-9.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Downloads/tm_0.5-9.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status.
```

Therefore, I went ahead and downloaded the compatible **slam** package from the [CRAN archives](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/). I downloaded **slam_0.1-26**

I tried to install it using

```
install.packages("/Downloads/slam_0.1-26.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

and got the following error

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'slam' ...
** package 'slam' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
**ERROR: compilation failed for package 'slam'**
* removing '/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/slam'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD INSTALL -l "/Documents/R/win-library/2.15"   "/Downloads/slam_0.1-26.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Downloads/slam_0.1-26.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How do I go about installing slam and eventually tm?

Comment: Do you have the compilation tools installed? Installing packages with an R version this old is going to be a serious uphill slog (version 3.0 came out in 2013, which is prehistoric by R standards). Assuming you have some very good reason for staying in the past, I would next try downloading the source tarball, unpacking it, and attempting to build/install it from the command line, which should give you access to more of the error messages.  Good luck ...

Comment: @BenBolker I shall try it out. Thank you! I am R with SPSS Modeler and therefore need this specific version because of compatibility issues!

Comment: Huh. Is this an old version of SPSS Modeler?  It looks like [version 17.1.0 of SPSS Modeler uses R 3.1.0](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_17.1.0/modeler_r_plugin_install_project_ddita/clementine/programmability_option/r_essentials_install_getr.html), while [version 18.0.0 uses R 3.2.2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_r_plugin_install_project_ddita/clementine/programmability_option/r_essentials_install_getr.html) ... the closer you can get to a modern version, the less pain you will have ...

Comment: @BenBolker Sadly I am stuck with SPSS Modeler 16 which is compatible with R 2.15.2. And I don't have the option of updating it any time soon.

Comment: Well, good luck.  I hope you're being paid well for this ...

Comment: I've had the same issue with compiling slam on OS X 10.11 with R 3.3.1; slam won't update past 0.1-37, for which CRAN had a pre-compiled binary.