# dependency ‘slam’ is not available when installing TM package

Tags: r, tm, slam

I was able to use the `library(tm)` in r without problem until today, when loading `tm` shows:

```
library(tm)
```

> Loading required package: NLP
>
> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
>
> there is no package called ‘slam’
>
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’

I thought this is a dependency issue and seek to reinstall package

```
install.packages("tm")
```

> Warning in install.packages : dependency ‘slam’ is not available

and then try to find `slam`:

```
install.packages("slam")
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>
> package ‘slam’ is not available (for R version 3.2.4)

I also tried some of the issues listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa) and `chooseCRANmirror()`, still no luck. Is there something wrong with the package or is it just that my r does not allow 'slam' to install after today?

**session info**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] NLP_0.1-9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] parallel_3.2.4 tools_3.2.4
```

Comment: whats your sessionInfo?

Comment: Just asked, though not solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884276/r-compilation-failed-for-package-slam

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian do you mean running `sessionInfo(package='slam')`? The result is "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : no package 'slam' was found"

Comment: @alistaire thanks! will keep an eye on that thread too, I am operating on OSX

Comment: No I meant, what environment are you working with? ``sessionInfo()``

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian thanks for the edits, I have updated the question with my `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to the newest R release.

Comment: Thanks! It's now solved after updating R to 3.3.1 and then `install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: That's odd. The current version of slam on CRAN fails the tests for OS X because with an error that it cannot be installed. https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-release-osx-x86_64-mavericks/slam-00check.html

Comment: @pdb so this solution doesn't work for you? that's weird indeed... I'm on a different OS X system but it shouldn't make the difference I suppose..

Comment: My post said that it didn't work for CRAN's test machine. When i ran install.packages("slam") I had to choose a version. If I chose to install from source it fails (this matches CRAN's results). The install binary version worked for me but gets you the previous version. Was your experience different?

Comment: After reinstalling `tm` with `dependencies = True` I did not have to choose a version to install.

Answer (score 38):

For *R-version 3.2.3*, following worked fine as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41482092/5916727) and it suggests this works for *R-version 3.3.0* as well:

```
#install devtools if you have not installed 
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)

slam_url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/slam_0.1-37.tar.gz"
install_url(slam_url)
```

Comment: Had to also install Rtools and then it worked. Not sure if Rtools can be used instead of devtools.

Comment: @Simone thanks! for the comment. May be it will helpful someone who may have similar issue.

Answer (score 34):

I found a hint at [this german site](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/R/) about R under Install additional R packages ("Zusätzliche R-Pakete installieren")
After I installed slam seperatly over apt-get for example:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-slam
```

I could install tm the normal way:

```
install.packages('tm')
```

And load the library aswell.

I hope my answer helps someone.

Comment: Worked a treat for me too.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem as you.
 [Slam](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html) "Depends:    R (≥ 3.3.1)", this why I had to perform the following actions to successfully install and load "tm" package:

1. Update R from 3.2.5 to the latest version 3.3.2
2. install.packages("tm")
   also installing the dependencies ‘NLP’, ‘slam’
   package ‘NLP’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   package ‘tm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
3. library(tm)

Comment: I tried installing it. It says "package ‘slam’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)"
That happened while installing package for tm. It did install NLP as the dependency.
And not throws error(of course) if i try to run anything related to these libraries.

Answer (score 5):

I used the following code to install the binary or the older version of slam. It worked for me.

```
install.packages("slam", type = "binary")
```

Comment: Great answer! Worked for me till R version upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and:

- I upgraded RStudio to the latest version (1.0.143)
- I upgraded R to the latest version (R.3.3.3)
- I rebooted Rstudio
- I installed again in RStudio the package "tm"
- I ran library(tm)

and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the package "slam" only works for R(>=3.4.0),so you can try either updating your R to the latest version or downloading an early version of the "slam" package.

This is a download link from CRAN for early version of "slam" package: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/slam_0.1-40.tgz.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem seems to be the version of R you are using. Try installing the latest version of R, 3.3.1. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using R3.2.5. I was trying to install "tm". I did install NLP as a dependency but gave me an error :

> "package ‘slam’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)"

The option I had to was to download the zip/tar/gz file(binaries) from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html and install the package.
It worked for me after that. Although I am not sure what the problem is because the library information mentions it is for R (≥ 3.3.1)

Answer (score 0):

I also had to upgrade to the most recent version of R.

Specifically, on Ubuntu 16.04 here are instructions to get the [up to date R version](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-16-04-2).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while installing the "tm" package on R version 3.3.0. Seems like some missing libraries. After I could install the latest version 3.4.1 , i was able to install the package "tm" which installed the 'slam' on its own. Hope this may help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just Install NLP package with `dependencies = True`
2. Install tm packaged with `dependencies = True`

And things should work out:)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu, I installed the following two from console and then it got installed.

`sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev`

`sudo apt-get install gfortran`

Answer (score -3):

For any such type of issue regarding package not installed, update your R and later reinstall the package. These are the steps you follow:

```
if(!require(installr)){ install.packages("installr")}

require(installr)}    #load the package

updateR()
```