# install.packages("tm") -> "dependency 'slam' is not available"

Tags: r, ibm-cloud, tm, data-science-experience, dsx

I'm trying to install the `tm` package on IBM's Data Science Experience (DSX):

```
install.packages("tm")
```

However, I'm hitting this issue:

```
"dependency 'slam' is not available"
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40273842/1033422) suggests that R version `3.3.1 will` resolve the issue, however the R version on DSX is: `R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)`

How can I resolve this issue on IBM DSX?  Note that you don't have root access on DSX.

I've seen similar questions on stackoverflow, but none are asking how to fix the issue on IBM DSX, e.g. [dependency ‘slam’ is not available when installing TM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885408/dependency-slam-is-not-available-when-installing-tm-package)

---

**Update:**

```
install.packages("slam")
```

Returns:

```
Installing package into '/gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/s85d-88ebffb000cc3e-39ca506ba762/R/libs'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning message:
"package 'slam' is not available (for R version 3.3.0)"
```

Comment: Did you get the same error when trying to install `slam` using `install.packages`?

Comment: Try some of the following: `available.packages()`, `install.packages("slam", type = "source")`

Comment: See the dependency stated [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html). You could try to install an older version of these packages.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll raise this with the product team for DSX.

Comment: did you try `install.packages("slam", method="curl")` ? it fixes many _... not available (for R version ...)_ errors

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error with curl.

Comment: R notebooks on #dsx now run on R-3.3.2 and installing the package `slam` works out of the box. In general, the approach suggested in the accepted answer is the correct way to satisfy dependencies among R packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try to install `slam` with `install.packages()`, then the version 0.1.40 will be used from CRAN. According to your error and the DESCRIPTION file of the library, it has the dependency on R (>= 3.3.1).

If a older version of `slam` is useful for you, then you can install it from the CRAN archives. See https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/

According to the documentation for `tm`, it has a dependency on slam (≥ 0.1-31). See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html

Previous versions have a dependency on older R versions. The following code worked for me to install `slam_0.1.37` on DSX:

```
library(devtools)
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/slam_0.1-37.tar.gz")

# test slam
library(slam)
a <- as.simple_sparse_array(1:3)
a
extend_simple_sparse_array(a, c( 0L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install slam either by

`install.packages("slam")`

OR

```
slam_url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/slam/slam_0.1-37.tar.gz"
install_url(slam_url)
```

Answer (score -3):

try
sudo apt-get install r-cran-slam
(worked for lubuntu)