# How to install package tm in R-3.3.0

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm using R-3.3.3. I tried to install package tm using following commands

```
install.packages('tm',dependencies = TRUE)
library('tm')
```

But I'm getting error message

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =  vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘slam’
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘tm’ was built under R version 3.3.3 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’

I saw two solutions for same type of error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419015/install-packagestm-dependency-slam-is-not-available) & [dependency ‘slam’ is not available when installing TM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885408/dependency-slam-is-not-available-when-installing-tm-package). I tried those two but I'm getting error message like

> Installation failed: Could not find build tools necessary to build slam.

Kindly suggest me how to install tm package in R-3.3.3

Comment: Perhaps slam requires RTools? Are you installing on windows? https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Yes, I'm using R-studio in Windows

Comment: Are you limited on R-3.3.3? I've checked with R-Studio and R-3.4.1 and am having no troubles installing `slam`

Comment: slam needs compilation, and as a consequence you need RTools installed to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today, after testing many ways to solve it I could find the following command that can install the `tm` package, sorry I know it is very late but still useful.

```
require(devtools)
install_version("tm", version = "0.7-1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```