# installing tm in older version of R Version 3.2.0

Tags: r, tm, slam

I would like to install the tm package and I am having great difficulty. I tried the traditional. I am using older version of R and it is causing issues. I am mac user using 10.10. 5 Yosemite and I cannot upgrade my R to next version as I need to have 10.11 version. Can someone suggest how I can get this working? I tried other things like installing slam which seems to be not working as well (this was the solution that was proposed in the 
[How to install package tm in R-3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056740/how-to-install-package-tm-in-r-3-3-0)

Any suggestions how I can approach this problem?

```
install.packages('tm')
  Warning in install.packages :
 dependency ‘slam’ is not available
```

Comment: R version 1.0.153 does not exist. My suspicion is that you are using a version of R (3.1.2, 3.2.3, 3.3.2,...) that is not maintained. It is always advisable to use a maintained version: (3.1.3, 3.2.5, 3.3.3) or the latest version (3.4.2). The best advice is to update R to 3.3.3 or 3.4.2. If not possible, then MS runs an archive of CRAN package repository. Find your version of R (open new instance, it is printed at top or type `R.Version()` in the console) and then go to https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/snapshot/2016-07-31/. Change the dates as necessary so that you find your version of R.

Comment: and use that URL as your repo in `install.packages`.

Comment: It is this version R version 3.2.0

Comment: thank you i was able to install version 3.3.3 and it worked fine!