# Unable to install tm package in R-Studio even though dependencies are set to TRUE

Tags: r

I have looked at answers here before, but when I tried them, all of them failed. I want to install `tm` package from R. I tried:

```
install.packages("tm", dependencies=TRUE)
```

but the output always was:

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘Rpoppler’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘tm’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you installing in UNIX?

Can you try to download the package from : (I tried and I manage to download it)

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rpoppler/index.html

Then try to install the tar.gz file offline? (ie. `Tools -> Install Packages`)

Comment: ok, installed the file, but when I type `library("Rpoppler")`, I get the error  `there is no package called "Rpoppler"`, how to solve this?

Comment: first try `library(Rpoppler)`. If can't, try to run `installed.packages()` and see if Rpoppler is there.

Comment: no, I dont see `Rpoppler` in the installed packages.

Comment: That means your installation may not be successful. Do you have libpoppler-glib-dev for (if for Debian/Ubuntu), or poppler-glib-devel  (if on Fedora)?
These libs package are required to build and install Rpoppler package in Linux. Install it from yum or rpm or download here https://poppler.freedesktop.org/. Then try to rebuild and install Rpoppler package. You must ensure your installation is successful first before loading the library using `library(Rpoppler)`

Comment: my main intent is to install the package `"tm"`. Whether installing this would really help?

Comment: Your `tm` package has Rpoppler as one of its dependecies which in turn require you to install all these packages. If you can install `tm` without requiring Rpoppler, then congratulation! Otherwise you can install `tm` on Windows environment instead because `tm` in Windows does not require Rpoppler.

Comment: just extracting the `tar.gz` and `tar.xz` files would mean they are installed right?

Comment: You have to do `Tools -> Install Packages` in your Rstudio to *build and install* it. If you just extract it in some folders, how does R know how to find your package?

Comment: R CMD INSTALL package.tar.gz. Is this the first time you manually build and install R's binary source package? You can look this up. Stack Overflow is meant to solve a problem that you have tried to solve, not to spoonfeed.

Comment: I can clearly see Rpoppler installed on my system using File Mananager. But still, the result is the same. I am herewith pasting what I see in my terminal on typing the install argument: `install.packages("Rpoppler")
Installing package into ‘/home/prajnan/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/src/contrib/Rpoppler_0.1-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 38275 bytes (37 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 37 KB`

Comment: `** package ‘Rpoppler’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about poppler-glib >= 0.18.0... no
configure: error: cannot determine poppler-glib compile/link flags
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rpoppler’
* removing ‘/home/prajnan/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rpoppler’

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpZ0uqPT/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rpoppler") :
  installation of package ‘Rpoppler’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: I am sorry, but am desperate, as I could load other packages, but not this one.

Comment: thanks, though your answer had a role to play, but the main help was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885408/dependency-slam-is-not-available-when-installing-tm-package), finally installed the package tm

Comment: Im glad it is solved. Thanks for linking to the help page as well. It helps build up my knowledge too.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with that `Rpoppler` package.  Here's the error I get when I try to install it:

```
> install.packages("Rpoppler")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/alebel/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Rpoppler’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
```

Sorry if that's not the answer you were hoping for.

Comment: so, how do I circumvent the problem?