# tm package installation errors in R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"

Tags: r, tm, slam

I am trying to work with tm package in R on my Macbook Pro (late 2011) running under macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6. The tm package has been installed but when I load it, I receive the following error message

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘slam’
```

Then I tried to install slam and got this:

````
  There is a binary version available but the source
  version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
slam 0.1-45 0.1-46              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) y
installing the source package ‘slam’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/slam_0.1-46.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 53515 bytes (52 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 52 KB

* installing *source* package ‘slam’ ...
** package ‘slam’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c apply.c -o apply.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c dll.c -o dll.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c grouped.c -o grouped.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c sparse.c -o sparse.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c util.c -o util.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o slam.so apply.o dll.o grouped.o sparse.o util.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [slam.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘slam’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/slam’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘slam’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/zq/lzsw_rp15sj3wtfvb3r0kksc0000gn/T/RtmpX95gez/downloaded_packages’```
Can anyone please help me fix this?
Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

I have come across exactly the same issue today. I'm running R 3.6.1 (as you are) on a Mac Book Pro using macOS Mojave (10.14.6), and I have the same error messages.

I tried some of the answers from here:
[dependency ‘slam’ is not available when installing TM package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885408/dependency-slam-is-not-available-when-installing-tm-package)

by trying:

```
install.packages("NLP", dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("tm", dependencies = TRUE)
```

.....but no joy.

So I went to here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html
And downloaded `slam_0.1-45.tgz` to my Downloads folder
And then installed it directly from there, using:

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/slam_0.1-45.tgz", repos = NULL, type = .Platform$pkgType)
```

And it seems to now install the tm package fine.